# In Perl OOP, is there any official recommendations on initialisation within the constructor?

Tags: perl, oop

In Perl Object Oriented Programming, is there any official[1] recommendations for the separation or inclusion of initialisation in the "new" constructor?

I'm seeking references to Perl Best Practices or similar.

For example is there an official recommendation for the split or combined form of the following:

```
sub new {
   my ( $obj_or_class ) = @_;

   my $class = ( ref $obj_or_class ) ? ref $obj_or_class : $obj_or_class;
   my $self = bless {}, $class;
   return $self;
} ## end sub new

sub init {
   my ( $self, $arg ) = @_;
      foreach my $key (@VALID_KEYS) {
       if ( exists $arg->{$key} ) {
           $self->{$key} = $arg->{$key};
       }
   }
   return;
} ## end sub _init
```

[1] I realise "official" within the Perl community is a pretty loose concept.

Answer (score 1):

The latest word is to not roll your own object system, but instead to use [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) or one of it's derivatives.

`Moose` will automatically provide you with a constructor, and you can define initialization on a per field basis.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a *constructor* returns a blessed object, and a method operates on that object. An easy way to tell is to look at the first parameter. Is it named `$class` or `$self`?

It is common practice to call the subroutine that acts a constructor as `new`. This makes it easy to figure it out. Also, it's common practice to put the constructors first in your package before the methods.

In real Perl, you have nothing that enforces any of this. My favorite are [inside-out classes](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col63.html) which are popular because you can't *cheat* by using classes as references. It's Perl's answer to *private* methods. To me, it makes programming and debugging impossible to do, and maintain.

Of course, the latest way is to not roll your own, but to use Moose, or Mouse, or one of the many derivatives. of Moose. You can even use [Class::Struct](http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html) which unlike all of the other modules is a standard Perl module.