# Do you have to name constructors 'new' in object-oriented Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

I wrote some object-oriented Perl and I used the `new` keyword as the name of my constructor. If I change `new` to `car`, it still works.

Is `new` a predefined keyword required for constructors or can you use your own constructor name?

Answer (score 8):

`new` is not a keyword, and it has absolutely no meaning to Perl. `bless` is what constructs objects. If you want a constructor called `load`, that's no problem. `car` doesn't seem to be a good choice of name for a constructor. But as you said, it works too.

Comment: so why most of the module use new key word to create object , why not we use other keyword? is any thing special in new?

Comment: Because when you see `new`, you know it's a constructor. It would be bad to name a non-constructor `new` as it would cause confusion, and naming a constructor something other than `new` should only be done with care for the same reason.

Comment: It's to make the C++ and Java programmers feel like they know what's going on

Comment: @mob, I strongly disagree. A convention would develop even if Perl was the only language.

Comment: For sure, but it is hardly a coincidence that the convention that did develop emulated two very popular object-oriented languages, especially when indirect object syntax (`... = new MyClass`)  wasn't as frowned upon as it is today.

Comment: @mob, The choice of the word `new` is due to its use elsewhere yes, but only using `new` has nothing to do with comforting anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the `perlootut`:

> In Perl, there is no special keyword for constructing an object. However,
>   most OO modules on CPAN use a method named "new()" to construct a new
>   object

I suggest you to experiment how it works by running the following perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

package A;
sub new { say "hello: @_"; bless [] }

package B;
sub new { say "world: @_"; bless [] }
sub old { say "hi: @_" };

package main;

# This prints 'hello: 1 2 3', since it calls directly the sub A::new
A::new(1,2,3);

# Equivalent forms, print 'hello: A 1 2 3'
new A(1,2,3);
A->new(1,2,3);
# Both forms call the A::new sub and pass a string "A" as first argument.

# The bareword B is used this time. Perl knows the B::new function
# must be called. "B" is passed as first parameter.
# This prints 'world B 1 2 3'
my $b = new B(1,2,3);

# Prints something similar to 'hi: B=ARRAY(0x16b7630) 4 5 6'
# A blessed reference always carries around as context information
# about its package.
$b->old(4,5,6);

# Equivalent
B::old($b, 4, 5, 6);
```

Once you've understood this, you can see how the constructor is simply a function returning a blessed reference. You can call it whatever you want.

It is important to notice the difference between `A::new` and `A->new`, since only the second form uses the package name as first parameter. In line of principle, the user of your package might call `new` in both ways. In the example we are not using the parameters except for printing, but if you are using them, you'd better document how people should call your construtor.

See also this related question: [In Perl OOP, is there any official recommendations on initialisation within the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976044/in-perl-oop-is-there-any-official-recommendations-on-initialisation-within-the?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any name you like to the constructor of its class. But it is good always to think of the difficulties that may occur to others or yourself, if you do not follow this convention.

It is good practice, increases comprehension in reading code written by others. It is also good to note that there are many ways (*TMTOWTDI*) to program object-oriented Perl. The official documentation is very clear and useful: [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) and [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). **Moose** is the recommended way, but there are many others, including using "primitive" form.

If you are programming in primitive form --- not recommended --- the key is to use **bless** in its constructor, and the name makes no difference to the code to be functional, but it is important for readability and understanding.